# kubectl patch returning service not found

Tags: kubernetes, raspberry-pi, kubernetes-helm, k3s, pihole

I have deployed pihole on my k3s cluster using this helm chart https://github.com/MoJo2600/pihole-kubernetes.
(I used this [tutorial](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2020/raspberry-pi-cluster-episode-4-minecraft-pi-hole-grafana-and-more))
I now have my services but they dont have external IPs:

```
NAME             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
pihole-web       ClusterIP   10.43.58.197    <none>        80/TCP,443/TCP   11h
pihole-dns-udp   NodePort    10.43.248.252   <none>        53:30451/UDP     11h
pihole-dns-tcp   NodePort    10.43.248.144   <none>        53:32260/TCP     11h
pihole-dhcp      NodePort    10.43.96.49     <none>        67:30979/UDP     11h
```

I have tried to assing the IPs manually with this command:

```
kubectl patch svc pihole-dns-tcp -p '{"spec":{"externalIPs":["192.168.178.210"]}}'
```

But when executing the command i'm getting this error:

```
Error from server (NotFound): services "pihole-dns-tcp" not found
```

Any Ideas for a fix?
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: That "external IP" column doesn't actually do anything.  It's only usually set if you have a LoadBalancer-type service and there's a controller that creates an out-of-cluster load balancer; there's no practical effect whether it's set or not.  I'd skip this command entirely.  (It'd be better to configure your application via Helm chart parameters than to manually `kubectl patch` or `kubectl edit` it in any case.)

Comment: @DavidMaze thx for the answer. But just out of curiosity do you have an idea why i cant find the services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Looks Like "pihole-dns-tcp" is in a different namespace to the namespace where patch command is being ran.
- As per the article you have shared , it seems like service `pihole-dns-tcp` is in `pihole` . So the command should be

`kubectl patch svc pihole-dns-tcp -n pihole -p '{"spec":{"externalIPs":["192.168.178.210"]}}'`